# Convert a Date to Julian Date and then Store in a Numeric Field in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a date field in a T-SQL variable which I want to convert to Julian Date Format and then insert in to a `Numeric` column in a table. Can someone please help?

I saw there are some posts on Julian Date but I am not able to get through.

EX :

```
declare @d datetime 
Set @d = GetDate()
select datediff(d, 0, @d) + 693596
```

The above statement does convert in to a julian date but not in the correct format. For example if today is 15 Feb 2014 then this should convert this in to 114046 but it converts this to 735279.

Also once this gets converted to correct julian format. I want to convert this to Numeric as I want to insert to a `numeric` column in a table.

I am sorry if this question has been asked previously. I am new to SQL Server 2005.

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 9):

Give this a go:

```
DECLARE @input_date DATETIME

SELECT @input_date = getdate()

SELECT datepart(year, @input_date) * 1000 + datepart(dy, @input_date)
```

Answer (score 7):

The above answer doesn't seem to work for me.

```
--If Julian Format is defined as CYYJJJ where: 
--  C is the number of centuries since 1900-01-01 
--  YY is the 2 digit year 
--  JJJ is the day number of the given YY year

--Convert Date => Julian uning CYYJJJ

declare @date datetime = '02/15/2014' 
select (datepart(year, @date)-1900)*1000 + datepart(dy, @date) 
--output: 114046

--Convert Julian => Date using CYYJJJ

declare @jdate int = 114046 
select dateadd(dd, (@jdate - ((@jdate/1000) * 1000)) - 1, dateadd(yy, @jdate/1000 - 1900, 0))
--output: '02/15/2014'

---

--Convert Date => Julian uning YYYYJJJ

declare @dateB datetime = '02/15/2014' 
select (datepart(year, @dateB))*1000 + datepart(dy, @dateB) 
--output: 114046

--Convert Julian => Date using YYYYJJJ
declare @jdateB int = 2014046 
select dateadd(dd, (@jdateB - ((@jdateB/1000) * 1000)) - 1, dateadd(yy, @jdateB/1000 - 1900, 0)) 
--output: '02/15/2014'
```

I would suggest putting that into a Scalar Function so you can execute it like:

```
select dbo.FromJulianDate(2014046)
```

sourced from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic778671-169-1.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The following will give an 7 character julian date output of: YYYYDDD

```
SELECT datepart(year, @input_date) * 1000 + datepart(dy, @input_date)
```

The following will give an 6 character julian date output output of: CYYDDD

```
SELECT CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @input_date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @input_date)))
```

Further explanation

- Julian dates start from 1900-01-01
- The C element is the century from 1900.
  If the year is 1950, the C part will be 0
  If the year is 2000, the C part will be 1 (and this increases with each 100 years)
- The DDD element reflects the number of days from the beginning of the
  year so 28th February will be 058

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CONCAT((DATEPART(year, @date) -1900),(DATEPART(dy, @date)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
SET @date = '2014-2-15';
SELECT @date,
       YEAR(@date),
       DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date),
       (YEAR(@date) - 1900) * 1000 + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) JulianDate;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have somewhat of a simpler answer that I came up with..
You can edit what you want to display, with some simple replacing.

The query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @t_stamp datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @year char(4)   = RIGHT(DATEPART(year, @t_stamp),1) 
DECLARE @jday char(4)   = RIGHT('000'+CAST(DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,  @t_stamp) AS varchar(3)),3)

SELECT RTRIM(@year) + @jday
```

***Breakdown***

Start off by declaring your starting datetime

```
DECLARE @t_stamp datetime = GETDATE()
```

Then set the year - starts from right to left

```
DECLARE @year char(4) = RIGHT(DATEPART(year, @t_stamp),1) 
--Changing '1' to '2' will give me 22 otherwise just 2.
```

then set your julian day (3 digits)

```
DECLARE @jday char(4) = RIGHT('000'+CAST(DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @t_stamp) AS varchar(3)),3)
```

Finally do your SELECT statement - you can append anything to this to make it unique or just cast it as an int.

```
SELECT  'SB-' + RTRIM(@year) + @jday
```

Your Result (Today's date 1/25/2022)

```
SB-2025
```

Answer (score 0):

(Since this is the highest ranked result in google) . . .
In case you need to turn this into an expression statement in a SSIS package, you can use this

```
(DT_WSTR, 50)(((YEAR(GETDATE())-1900)*1000)+DATEPART("dy", GETDATE()))
```

For example:

```
"SELECT somefield FROM " + @[User::FileHeaderTable] + " WHERE JdeDate = "+ (DT_WSTR, 50)(((YEAR(GETDATE())-1900)*1000)+DATEPART("dy", GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the known values here are two solutions I have personally utilized which I first did in NodeJS then converted to MSSQL when trying to get Julian Microsecond.

I had a known value in Gregorian and Julian Microsecond and so I just had to convert bridge the two and used  https://www.aavso.org/jd-calculator as a check along the way. I used this answer to

```
/* Known Values:
   Gregorian: 2021-03-03 21:55:00.000
   Julian; 2459277.41319 ) 
   JulianMicrosecond: 212481593700000000
*/
```

I used this [answer along the way to develop my Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864741/converting-gregorian-date-to-julian-date-and-then-back-again-with-time) code.

```
let getJulainDay = (Year,Month,Day) => {
  a = parseInt((14 - Month) / 12);
  y = Year + 4800 - a;
  m = Month + 12 * a - 3;
  JDN =
    (Day +
    parseInt(
      ( 
      (153 * m + 2) / 5) +
      (365 * y) +
      parseInt(y / 4) -
      parseInt(y / 100) +
      parseInt(y / 400) -
      32045 )
    ) 
   //Into  Julian Microseconds 24*60*60*1e6 
    * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000; 
  return JDNMicroSeconds;
};
```

Then I mapped this into MSSQL that I had to treat a bit differently, noting that I had to enter all integer values in the formula above as floats or I would have had to cast each result.. it was just easier to enter them as floats.. if I don't do this I only get integer results and it throws the results off by years.

This is definitely an overly verbose breakdown but it allows you to see the steps along the way.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;

SET @date = '2021-03-03 21:55:00.000';
SELECT @date,
       YEAR(@date) as Year,
       DATEPART(MONTH,@date) as Month,
       DATEPART(DAY,@date) as Day,
       DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) as DofY,
       14 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date)) as mm,
       ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0) as A,
       (YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) as Y,
       ( DATEPART(MONTH,@date) + (12.0 * ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) -3.0) as M,
       /* Watch the order of operations/parethesis! */
       (DATEPART(DAY,@date) + 
       ((153.0 * (( DATEPART(MONTH,@date) + (12.0 * ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) -3.0)) + 2.0) / 5.0) + 
       (365.0 * ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)))) +
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 4.0) -
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 100.0) +
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 400.0) -
       32045.0) as JDN,
       (DATEPART(DAY,@date) + 
       ((153.0 * (( DATEPART(MONTH,@date) + (12.0 * ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) -3.0)) + 2.0) / 5.0) + 
       (365.0 * ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)))) +
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 4.0) -
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 100.0) +
       ((YEAR(@date) + 4800.0 - ((14.0 -(DATEPART(MONTH, @date))) / 12.0)) / 400.0) -
       32045.0) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000 as JDNMicroSecond,
       /* What others proposed which I do not believe is correct. */
       (YEAR(@date) - 1900) * 1000 + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) IncorrectJDN;
```

The output being:
[image]