# Convert SQL Date to JDE Date

Tags: sql, xslt, date-conversion

I have an input date in format `2017-07-27T10:00:00Z` which needs to be converted into JDE(117208), can anyone help me how to do it in SQL or XSLT. I really appreciate your help.

I need a SQL Query for the same

`input format`  : 2017-07-27T10:00:00Z
`output format` : 117208

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Date to Julian Date and then Store in a Numeric Field in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801638/convert-a-date-to-julian-date-and-then-store-in-a-numeric-field-in-sql-server-20)

Comment: shouldn't the expected Julian date be 2457960 for an input of 2017-07-27?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO FYI. http://jderef.com/ in this site on the top right we can see the todays date and respective julian date. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No, that's the JDE date. Not the Julian date.

Comment: Oh k. Thanks for the information. can you please let me know how to get it.

Comment: If you're asking how to do this in XSLT, please state if you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you need.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('2017-07-27T10:00:00Z', 'T', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') AS DATE), 'J') as JULIAN
FROM    dual
```

Comment: Hi JRG but the julain date that I'm expecting is 117208 for the given date. can you please help me out.

Comment: for the input 2017-07-27T10:00:00Z the expected Julian date is 117208(CYYDDD) Format.

Answer (score 0):

simple you can do this in one line:

```
select dat, concat(datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) /100,datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) % 100, datepart(DAYOFYEAR,dat) ) as JDE from d
```

I stored your example input data in a table call d under column dat:

```
dat        JDE
---------- ------------------------------------
2017-07-27 117208
```

**Explanation:**

first it is important to understand what is JDE julian date. it is in this format CYYDDD:

- **C** stands for centuries and it starts at the 20th century (hence the hard coded date `1900-01-01` in my query). C is 0 if the years of 19xx. C is 1 for the years of 2000. This is why we took your date and get the number of different years since 1900-01-01 and divided it by 100 to get the number of centuries. `datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) /100`
- **YY** stands for the years in the century. so if the year is 2089 the first three digit of JDE would be 189DDD `datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) % 100` helps you get the remainder of the century which is the years.
- **DDD** is the day of the year. In sql server there is a very nice to get day of the year using `datepart(DAYOFYEAR,dat)`

Now we get all three parts of JDE we `concat()` them together and you have your JDE year.

EDIT:

I added some logic to ensure all fields would have proper 0 paddings.

```
SELECT dat ,CONCAT(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(1),datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) / 100),1) , RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(2), datediff(year,'1900-1-1',dat) % 100),2), RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3),datepart(DAYOFYEAR,dat)),3)) from d
```

Comment: can you please make it clear. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think the expected output is JDE date

Comment: ahhh that makes more sense. I think I still know how to do this. Let me work on it and I will update my answer when I am done.

Comment: I updated it and I will add some explanations to it. In the mean time see if it worked for you

Comment: I'm not so perfect in SQL. I really appreciate if you can make it clear.

Comment: just substitute dat with the date you desire to convert. If you are using this for a one time use. you can put your date in the query. `select concat(datediff(year,'1900-1-1','2017-07-27') /100,datediff(year,'1900-1-1','2017-07-27') % 100, datepart(DAYOFYEAR,'2017-07-27') ) as JDE ` but I wouldn't recommand doing that

Comment: I executed above SQL statement but its throwing an error ;)

Comment: Invalid characters

Comment: are you using sql server? did you executed the exact query I posted above? It works fine for me? and are you doing this for one time use? or you have a table of dates you want to convert to JDE? When you comment please give as much information as possible so I can help you debug.

Comment: I know you are using SQL. but which DBMS implementation are you using? MySQL? Oracle? MS SQL Server? they have different syntax that is could by why you are getting an error. When you ask a sql related question remember to tag the DBMS implementation you are using. Also I encourage you to try to understand the query yourself, my explanation should help you understand it. If you can understand it then you can further modify or substitute the query to get your answer. Don't expect you can copy and past code from SO and have people do your work for you.

Comment: Oracle we are u

Comment: The syntax I used in my code is sal server. Just go ahead change the syntax to use Oracle for the parts needed. And what do you mean by "we r u"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the date format used by JDE, namely CYYDDD, is often referred to within the JDE user community as a Julian date, but it actually has nothing to do with Julian day numbers as the term is commonly understood in the rest of the world. (And furthermore, just to be quite clear, Julian day numbers have nothing to do with the Julian calendar.)

When used correctly, a Julian day number refers to a 24-hour period starting at noon, though I'm sure that doesn't apply to JDE dates.

So you have confused everyone by talking of Julian dates rather than JDE dates.

In XSLT 2.0 you can get the last five characters of the JDE date using

```
format-date($date, '[Y01][d001]')
```

But for the first character you'll need custom logic:

```
if ($date lt xs:date('2000-01-01')) then '0' else '1'
```

or if you prefer,

```
year-from-date($date) idiv 100 - 19
```

which has the advantage of working beyond 2100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
select DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())*1000+DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())-1900000
```

Date format should be (YYYY-MM-DD)